# Set multiple variables to avoid div/0 error

Tags: excel, vba

Hi To avoid a div/0 error I have to add

```
If a=0 then a=1
if b=0 then b=1
if c=0 then c=1
if d=0 then d=1 etc
```

Is there a one line solution for multiple variables?

Comment: Use `IsError()` function.

Comment: It's difficult to come up with an appropriate solution if you don't include the actual lines which cause the problem.

Comment: its not really a problem its just the result of a calculation can be zero for these variables but when I move on to the next step zero isn't a usable result

Answer (score 0):

actuallly no, because you want to compare differents variables and values
but if you want to short code: you can use array, i mean you can create a array with all valiables

`ABC()` /*refers to number of variables you have/*

in this case you have 5 variables but if you want to use alphabet yo can

StrVaribales="a,b,c,d,e" /*for example 5 variables/*

```
ABC()=split(strVariables,",")
```

and then use "for" with "i" to 5

```
if AB(i)=0 then AB(i)=1
```